# Subquery in Hive Where Clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need help with this piece:

How can I write the following in HIVE...

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE colA = (SELECT MAX(date_column) FROM tableA)
```

I need to query only the latest current records from the table. I am storing dates as strings in hive as "yyyy-mm-dd".

Comment: SELECT dateCol
FROM tableA
JOIN
  (SELECT TO_DATE(dateCol) AS dDate
   FROM tableA
   ORDER BY TO_DATE(dateCol) DESC LIMIT 1) test ON test.ddate = tableA.dateCol

Answer (score 1):

Avoid a JOIN, use the analytics and windowing features:

> select * from (select *, rank() over (order by date_col desc) as rank
>   from tableA) S where S.rank = 1;

Comment: I tried a SHOW FUNCTIONS and RANK() is not listed as the function I can call?

Comment: [Windowing and Analytics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) introduced in version 0.11

Comment: I am using CDH 4.5, is there a way to upgrade HIVE?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(date_column) AS max_date_column
      FROM tableA) b
ON a.colA = b.max_date_column
```

Hope it helps

EDIT: I have no idea how I got to this old question, you probably solved  it long ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Hive 0.13+, you can use subqueries in WHERE statements.